# jQuery Widget Factory - Overridden private function is not receiving expected arguments (event, ui)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to create a custom slider widget by extending the [jQuery UI Slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/). When overriding the _slide() function I'm expecting two arguments (event, ui), but I'm getting the event object and two numbers instead.  My question is why the difference and/or how should I be declaring my function so that it gets the standard (event, ui) arguments?

Code snippet:

```
(function ( $ ) {
$.widget("test.slider2", $.ui.slider, {

     _slide : function(){
        console.log(arguments);
         //do stuff
         this._superApply(arguments);
    } 
});
}(jQuery));
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVM2u/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration for the _slide private method is

```
_slide: function( event, index, newVal ) {
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js line 300

not the same as the `slide` event. http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide

In the code for `_slide`, look for `this._trigger( "slide"`

This triggers the slide event that has the function(event, ui) signature, and should give you an idea how to use those values to get the ui object.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Being directed to the source helped me realize I wasn't considering custom events.  I'll spend more with the source next time.